# ng-repeat is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this
`["2017-03-09 ": Array[6], "2017-03-10 ": Array[2]]`

while doing `ng-repeat` it is not working:

```
<div ng-repeat="total in sortedOrders">
    <div class="col-75">{{total.id}}</div>
</div>
```

**fiidle** [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30635/)
and

[consoled image of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls0dz.png)

Please help.

Comment: Can you please show controller side code?

Comment: @AkashKC ,this is a big function and posting the same wont be relevent

Comment: ["2017-03-09 ": Array[6], "2017-03-10 ": Array[2]] this is not valid code. You probably have an object {"...": "..." }. Ng-repeat doesn't work with objects

Comment: Your binding is perfectly right but I suspect it in your array of objects.

Comment: That array seems to be invalid ?

Comment: Try to give it like this {"2017-03-09 ": Array[6], "2017-03-10 ": Array[2]} with object notation.

Comment: plz show the values inside inner array

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: I think you would have to use two ng-repeats for this

Comment: i have added a fiddle

Comment: Your sortedOrders contains no elements, so ng-reapeat works perfectly fine

Comment: can u check my fiddle.. and see console. i m consoling  sortedOrders

Answer (score 0):

`["2017-03-09 ": Array[6], "2017-03-10 ": Array[2]]` is not the syntax for an array.

An array is a series of comma-separated values, like this:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

You should use an object instead if you would like to store a series of key-value pairs:

```
{
   one: 1,
   two: 2,
   three: 3
}
```

Comment: i have added the consoled image of array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two ng-repeat for this object as you have  arrays inside object and these array contains objects too.
So first ng-repeat walk through all outer values of object and this value is an array so inner loop traverses through this array for each object and put the id value of the object into the div.

```
   <div ng-repeat="inner in sortedOrders">
       <div ng-repeat="total in inner">
          <div class="col-75">{{total.id}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can u make a fiddle

Comment: this is fine. but mine is an array.not an object

Answer (score 0):

You have array inside of an array, what I got from your consoled image.
For that, you have to use two ng-repeat loops, if you want to show all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I suposse you are creating array like this:
`

```
var specialArray = [];
  // assigning values to corresponding keys
  specialArray["Main"] = [{id:1}];
  specialArray["Guide"] = [{id:2},{id:3}];
```

`

but that is not recognized by angular template (check my plunker). Try using plain object instead (also example in plunker).

In your JSFidlle change:

```
$scope.sortedOrders= []; 
    to 
$scope.sortedOrders= {};
```

and use:

```
<div ng-repeat="(d,value) in sortedOrders">
     {{value}}
   </div>
```

Example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B9xkncBZ71PyMvATYWHJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Edit in your plunker like:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2></h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="d in sortedOrders">
     <div ng-repeat="(f,value) in d">
     {{value.id}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and

`$scope.sortedOrders=[]; to $scope.sortedOrders={};`

You will get your ID Printed in the HTML page